# How to sort product collection by sales in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, sql, best-practice

I need to sort products on catalog page by ordered quantity.

What is the best way to do it?

I know that table `sales_order_item` contains this data, but I think direct SQL queries is bad practice (like **`SELECT SUM(qty_ordered) FROM sales_order_items WHERE product_id = {$product id}` and then sort it**).

So I want to find good solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution myself:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollection->create()
    ->joinField(
        'qty_ordered',
        'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly',
        'qty_ordered',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        array('store_id' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()),
        'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setOrder('qty_ordered');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create new attribute for products and save/update number of sales in this attributes. Then you can sort by new attribute using native magento interface.

Comment: Do you mean create _afterSave to order model and increment this attribute?

Comment: Yes. Or create plugin <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <plugin name="eventSalesOrderStatus" type="....."/>
    </type>

Comment: My techlead says it is bad practice

Comment: What is good practice?

Comment: I've just posted topic about this ) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194058/how-to-sort-products-by-bestsellers-e-g-by-sales-in-magento-2